# How to validate Windows account and password with Perl?

Tags: perl, powershell

I have solved this in Powershell 2.0, but need to port to Perl 5.10 for a legacy app.

I have Windows service account credentials which cannot INTERACTIVELY LOGON passed to a perl script as `$Account` and `$Password`. The `$Account` variable includes the domain name and AD user account name. My Powershell solution (one-liner) is:

```
PS C:\> New-PsSession -Credential (new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist '$Account', (ConvertTo-SecureString '$Password' -AsPlainText -Force)); exit-PsSession;
```

If the new PsSession gets created then the account validation passed and I get output to STDOUT like:

```
 Id Name            ComputerName    State    ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----    -----------------     ------------
  1 Session1        localhost       Opened   Microsoft.PowerShell     Available
```

If the validation failed I get output like this to STDERR:

```
[localhost] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message
 : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
 Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:Re
   moteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I can parse these results in my program. I want to do a similar thing in Perl 5.10 on Windows. All I want to do is test that a password works for an account bearing in mind that interactive logon is denied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach is to contact AD directly using [Net::LDAP](https://metacpan.org/module/MARSCHAP/perl-ldap-0.57/lib/Net/LDAP.pod), but then you have a lot of new challenges.

I also used something like the following (calling win ole) long time ago. But had to abandon on win200X-server i think. If it may be of any help: (Please excuse poor coding)

But this will actually check that the current user is a member of a group.
I presume it may be used to verify username pwd somehow as well.

```
require Win32::OLE;
sub GetObject {
    Win32::OLE->GetObject(@_);
}

    my ( $module, $database, $mode ) = @_;
    my $env = {%ENV}; #makes a copy, makes it possible to override $ENV for test etc
    my $oRoot = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE");
    my $domain_name =  $oRoot && $oRoot->Get("defaultNamingContext");
    my $domain_host =  $oRoot && $oRoot->Get("dnsHostName");

    $domain_host .= "/" unless $domain_host =~ /\/$/;
    my $strAttributeName  ="sAMAccountname"; #could be userPrincipalName, cn etc
    my @user_parts = ($user_name); # the last one (i.e. -1) will be the user name
    my $alias = $user_name;

    my $group_prefix = $system_info_defs->{adAuthGroupPrefix};
    my $strADsPath        = "LDAP://$domain_host$domain_name";
    my $objConnection = Win32::OLE->new("ADODB.Connection") 
        or do{warn "Cannot create ADODB Connection!";return undef};#die ("Cannot create ADODB object!");
    my $objCommand = Win32::OLE->new("ADODB.Command") 
        or do{warn "Cannot create ADODB command!";return undef};#die ("Cannot create ADODB object!");

    $objConnection->{Provider} = ("ADsDSOObject");
    $objConnection->Open();
    $objCommand->{ActiveConnection} = ($objConnection);
```

etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

use a system call from perl i.e. backticks

```
my $a = `powershell -command "ls;exit;"`;
if ($a =~ /pl$/) {
    print "folder contains a perl file";
} else {
    print "folder contains no perl file (strange)";
}
```

if this works then replace the simple ls-command with your more complex text.
Probalby you may need to elaborate on \" " ' \' "" and '' to get it right.

Comment: I did try that and the powershell process does not return. I've spent a few days on it with Win32::Spawn, Win32:Process:CreateProcess, qw(), system(), `` and none of it works from my calling process, so I'm wondering if it's possible natively in Perl without calling a powershell process.

Comment: did you end with ;exit; ?

Comment: from commandline c:>perl -e "print '123'.\`powershell -command ls;exit\`.432"

Comment: Yes I ended with ;exit. It works from a cmd.exe window, but does not work from my calling program and when I look in Task Manager I see a powershell.exe process.